# How to translate several values in the same cell into another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am working with a google sheet that has two sheets on it. One is a list of duties, and the users that are performing those, and the other is a user list. They look like this:

**Example:**

```
USERS:
ID   NAME
1    Chris
2    Pat
3    Steve
Duties:
ID   NAME   USERS
1    Clean  1
            3
__________________
2    Cook   2
            3
```

The users ids are stored in the same cell per duty, and I was wondering if it is possible to translate the ID's to the user's names in a seperate cell, but have the User's names still be in one cell?

So I would be getting:

```
Duties:
ID   NAME   USERS    Usernames
1    Clean  1        Chris
            3        Steve
_________________
2    Cook   2        Pat
            3        Steve
```

Is this possible?
Thank you!

Here is a Google sheet version: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QJ18MyO0xDI4B1CIQkz86bdSaKWl1btqkLXAatpux_w/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You talking about vlookup function. See the example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1frh2WDjRjBOjSGO6YyOq0I6l0SV1ASdd5TUomc4hj9E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is about what I need, but like I said in the post, all of the User IDs for the "Duties" sheet are in the same cell, per job

Comment: Ok, you may use split,join and vlookup . See the updated example.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1frh2WDjRjBOjSGO6YyOq0I6l0SV1ASdd5TUomc4hj9E/edit?usp=sharing